# Android development: [HOW TO] intercept daily alarm and dismiss programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, dismiss

I'd like to implement an Activity that launches a Service able to intercept/receive the daily scheduled clock alarm and dismiss it programmatically when an event is fired (i.e. a recognize speech event).
In practice I have:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
...
}
```

registered on a ALARM_ALERT_ACTION (com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT) [i've read that this works only with the system clock app]
Now when the Alarm ring MyReceiver.onReceive(...) method is called correctly but i can't dismiss (neither snooze) the alarm by code.
I've founded many examples use AlarmManager instance with .cancel(PendingIntent) method call but probably this works only when the alarm is scheduled by a custom Intent.
I've tried also getting all running processes and kill the com.android.deskclock process but is a not working way.

So, to summarize, I've scheduled a daily alarm with the system android clock app and i'd like to have a service that intercept com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT action/event and dismiss it by code.
Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 1):

I've founded how to do...check the code below:

```
AlarmManager alrm = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(MyService.ALARM_DISMISS_ACTION);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
alrm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 1000, pi);
```

In practice with these instructions I launch a "dismiss" alert event and this produce a current alarm ring dismission ;)

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to dismiss an alarm would be to either 1) intercept the alarm broadcast and redirect it to a false boolean, or 2) if the alarm app had an API to call.

Comment: Thanks in advance, for the option 1) how i can translate in code "redirect it to a false boolean"?

Comment: Basically, when the alarm broadcast is sent to the receiver, the receiver at some point will return a `true` because it's being triggered (or, at least, some sort of variable).  At that point, just call something that will send it right back to the listening state.